# How to keep all bash history

Tags: command-line, bash, bash-history

I want to keep my duplicates and all commands started with a space. How do I do that? I have no ideas what to do. Last time that I messed with bash nothing worked at all afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Open `.bashrc` using your favorite editor, for example:

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Then find:

```
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
```

Change it to:

```
#HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
```

And save the file.

Now duplicated commands and commands started with a space will be saved in your bash history too.